# in java webapp,hsqldb url won't accept relative path. is it due to maven configuration?

Tags: spring, maven, jakarta-ee, web-applications, hsqldb

i'm developing a webapp made up with 2 other maven modules.

i have the model module which representes database layer.it has spring application context `test-model-config.xml` in `test/resources/META-INF` for testing and the properties files in `test/resources' default package`. and `model-config.xml` in `resources/META-INF` which is the live context and which is supposed to pick properties from the webapp.
up to now builds fine, works fine no problem

```
-    <!-- test-model-config.xml and model-config.xml have the same thing-->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"  />
</bean>
```

here is just a snippet of the properties in test/resources

```
jdbc.driverClassName=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
jdbc.username=sa
jdbc.password=
jdbc.url=jdbc:hsqldb:file:target/mydb;create=true
```

there is another module services which has the same kind of conf where there is a test config and a live config files.this one too separately has no problem.builds fine , works fine.

now  the webapp there is `webapp-config.xml` in `/web pages/WEB-INF` and `general.properties` for all the properties needed for model and service modules. so `general.properties` and `webapp-log4j.properties` are in `resources' default package` of the webapp.here a snippet of `webapp-config.xml`

```
   <import resource="classpath:META-INF/model-config.xml" />
   <import resource="classpath:META-INF/service-config.xml" />
   <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
     <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:general.properties</value>
            <value>classpath:webapp-log4j.properties</value>
        </list>
     </property>
   </bean>
```

in the general.properties we have

```
jdbc.driverClassName=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
jdbc.username=sa
jdbc.password=
jdbc.url=jdbc:hsqldb:file:classpath:target/mynewdb;create=true
// ....
```

it also builds fine and runs fine with an issue.

**1** : the log says:

> java.sql.SQLException: File input/output error classpath:target/mynewdb.properties java.io.FileNotFoundException: classpath:target/mynewdb.properties.new (No such file or directory) full debug output is [here](http://pastie.org/1898735)

i'm really surprised because this is the first time i'm facing this kind of error.it's running fine with a absolute url as `/media/Repo/myproject/mydb;create=true`, but the idea is to have it in the the webapp target so that it got deleted when target folder is being deleted.

well i have no clue and it's been 2 days now.
How can id fix this? is here something i'm not seei/doing? is it due to maven configuration?
my pom is viewable [here](http://pastie.org/1915284)
thanks for reading this.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the syntax of `jdbc.url` in `general.properties` is incorrect - you cannot specify a `classpath` location for `file` - it has to be an absolute or relative path.  Refer to jdbcConnection [javadoc](http://hsqldb.org/doc/src/org/hsqldb/jdbc/jdbcConnection.html)

Comment: i removed the classpath keyword. it's there because the one i use for model module is working just fine.Even though i removed the classpath neither `jdbc.url=jdbc:hsqldb:file:mynewdb;create=true` nor `jdbc.url=jdbc:hsqldb:file:/mynewdb;create=true` nor `jdbc.url=jdbc:hsqldb:file:/target/mynewdb;create=true` nor `jdbc.url=jdbc:hsqldb:file:target/mynewdb;create=true` are working, but i believe, it follows connection string rules :
jdbc:hsqldb:file:<path>[<key-value-pairs>]' (same semantics as the legacy form)

Answer (score 1):

The database file path is relative to the current working directory of your JVM.

In the case you run your JVM from Maven sunfire plugin (for instance), you have to set the property `workingDirectory` (or corresponding option of any other plugin).

You may use `res:` mode instead of `file:` to get your database from classpath but it is limited to a read-only access.

Answer (score 0):

My HSQLDB file database is working by using the following JDBC URL:

```
jdbc:hsqldb:res:/db/mydb
```

Where mydb is the name of the HSQLDB file and is located in the following directory:

```
/WEB-INF/classes/db
```

Comment: As Yves Martin pointed out, this solution works but will limit the database to read-only access.